# is www.abc or www.www.com a valid url?

Tags: domains, url, dns

I know [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) is a valid URL but what about www.abc or even [www.www.com](http://www.www.com)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: None are valid URLs they are hostnames or domain names. URLs start with a scheme, like `http://` or `https://`

Comment: Ignoring the distinction between a URL and a domain name www.abc.com is valid, www.com is valid.  www.www.com is valid, www.abc is not valid, although the owner (American BroadCasting Companies Inc, or maybe even Disney Enterprises Inc) could register it.   It is possible that if you owned www.abc would work because www.abc does not exist, so depending on your OS and nameserver it might fall back by adding www.abc.com, or it might not.

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple matter of googling it.  It is valid.

[And Taken](https://www.whois.com/whois/www.com)

[image: Info]